# How to send JSON request with single string value in body with Spring Cloud OpenFeign

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I'm declaring FeignClient with Spring Cloud OpenFeign version 4.0.1. The API I'm calling expects in request body primitive JSON string value (e.g. `"something"`) as a string in quotes. But I'm struggling with implementing it using Feign.

Code sample:

```
@FeignClient(value = "client", url = "https://${example.host}:${example.port}/api/2/", dismiss404 = true)
public interface ExampleClient {
    @GetMapping(value = "/path/to/resource", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String getResourceValue();

    @PutMapping(value = "/path/to/resource", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    void setResourceValue(@RequestBody String hostname);
}
```

The code just serializes the string to body as plain text without adding quotes (it is even stripping them). In deserialization it returns the string including quotes and it is not removing them. I know this is intended behavior but how could I achieve that client will serialize and deserialize simple String value as valid JSON?

The only workaround I was able to find was to replace String type by Jackson `TextNode` class. But it is not very elegant solution. It was also possible by setting `JacksonEncoder` instead of Spring implementation but then I loose other features.

Answer (score 0):

Json request body consists of names of the parameters and values. If I understand correctly you want to send request like this:

```
{
    "hostname":"someValue"
}
```

In your code, feign have no idea what is the name of the parameter. You need to create a class which has one field - hostname. Like that:

```
public class Input {

private String hostname;

// add getters and setters

}
```

and then pass it as argument to you feign method:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/path/to/resource", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
void setResourceValue(@RequestBody Input input);
```

Feign will automatically map the field name to json field name.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually, I need to achieve that JSON request body will look just as string value (without property key): simply "someValue" as a body.
I'm using this workaround currently:
`void setResourceValue(@RequestBody TextNode hostname);`

Comment: Ok, but then it is not a JSON format. Valid JSON consists of  attribute–value pairs.

Comment: That's not correct - json support also primitive types except of objects: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt:

JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).

There are JSONPath based APIs which allow you to update single value.